# lateral animation and setInterval()

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, setinterval

I need to start, stop and restart a lateral animation with Javascript, with some search i found that Jquery `animate()` needs a plugin to do start-stop-restart, but i won't to use a plugin for do this (not waist your time to ask "why not?").

So, I asked me: "why you not use `setInterval()` to do this lateral animation and stop it with `clearInterval()`?

This is my code, is correct or is a crazy work for browser? I need to build a "efficent" (in terms of browser works) script but, I'm not the best about this. Have mercy plz.

```
window.newsflash.interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(liWidthTot + $('.fn_container ul').css("left") <= 0)
        $('.fn_container ul').css('left', containerWidth);
    $('.fn_container ul').css("left", "-=1px");
},10);

//handler
$("#xml").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        clearInterval(window.newsflash.interval);
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        window.newsflash.interval = setInterval(function() {
            if($('.fn_container ul').css("left") - liWidthTot <= 0)
                $('.fn_container ul').css('left', containerWidth);
            $('.fn_container ul').css("left", "-=1px");
        },10);
    }
});
```

its only a peace of my Js code... I not need to know how to... but if use setInterval() is a bad idea.

----- edit ----

Now:

```
var newsList = document.getElementById("newsList");
window.newsflash.interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(liWidthTot + parseInt(newsList.style.left) <= 0) newsList.style.left = containerWidth +"px";
    ewsList.style.left = (parseInt(newsList.style.left) -1) + "px";
},10);

//handler
$("#xml").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        clearInterval(window.newsflash.interval);

    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        window.newsflash.interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(liWidthTot + parseInt(newsList.style.left) <= 0) newsList.style.left = containerWidth +"px";
            newsList.style.left = (parseInt(newsList.style.left) -1) + "px";
        },10);
    }
})
```

Thx mates.

Comment: Check out this perfomance test (comparing js native setInterval and jQuery animate): http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-animation

Comment: Thx... was what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` is a perfectly legitimate way of doing animation. But using jQuery's `animate` method to start, stop, and restart an animation is also easy. To my eye, both solutions perform about the same, but it's up to you to decide which syntax seems more straightforward.

[Demo using jQuery's $.animate()](http://jsfiddle.net/nate/5HL2D/1/)

[Demo using setInterval()](http://jsfiddle.net/nate/8FUKx/)

In terms of performance, the main thing you want to do is make sure you're saving references to jQuery objects, rather than refetching them. You'll notice that in my examples I save the reference to the `ul` like this:

```
var $ul = $('.fn_container ul');
```

...so that it doesn't have to be fetched over and over.

Also: you might consider looking into CSS3 animations for a smoother look. You can even use something like [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) so that you can stick with jQuery animation syntax.